# How to Filter Odata Query that is expanded by multiple levels?

Tags: url, odata

I am currently trying to make an Odata call where I filter by a "multi-level" expanded property, however, none of the documentation or information I can find on this covers exactly what I am trying to accomplish. Does anyone know if this can be done, and how?

This is for letting our users be able to filter their Tests by the name of the Room the test was taken in. We have been able to filter by a single level of expanding, letting users filter their Tests by the name of the location, but we just can't seem to get the syntax right with the second level.

For context, our Test table is linked to a location table that is linked to a room table.

We are able to see the expanded information without a filter by calling:

> .../api/Tests$expand=Location($select=Id,LocationName;$expand=Room($select=Id,RoomName))

returns:

> ...{"Id":19955,"LocationId":102,"Location":{"Id":102,"LocationName":"TestLocation","Room":{"Id":8,"RoomName":"TestRoom"}},...

But when we try a filtered call such as:

> .../api/Tests$expand=Location($select=Id,LocationName;$expand=Room($select=Id,RoomName))&$filter=contains(Location/Room/RoomName,%27a%27))

All we get is the standard:

```
{"error":{"code":"NotFound","message":"The type 'Edm.String' is not an entity type. Only entity types support $select and $expand.\r\nParameter name: context"}}
```

There is surely some way of being able to filter from a multi-levelled expand, but I am somewhat of a newbie to Using OData, so any help would be appreciated!

Also, I believe we are using OData - 7.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question here, as it turns out the way we were doing it was correct.
The system was breaking in other areas down the pipe.